# Set up Backgroundworker MVVM, Update a Progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

I have got a StartCommand Class:

```
public class StartCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //Fill Listview1
        ...
        //Here I want to increase the Progressbarvalue   

        //Fill Listview2
        ...
        //Here again and so far..       
    }
}
```

Execute Command will be executed, when clicking the Startbutton on my `MainWindow.xaml` (where's also the `progressBar`).

What I want now, is **updating the Progressbar** on these places (look at Code), while the ListViews are loading. *How do I set up the Backgroundworker?*

I tried something like that:

```
public class StartCommand : ICommand
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow;

        public StartCommand(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
             this.mainWindow = mainWindow
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //Fill Listview1
            ...
            mainWindow.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(10);  

            //Fill Listview2
            ...
            mainWindow.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(20);      
        }
    }
```

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeBackgroundWorker();
    }

    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork +=
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted +=
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        e.Result = UpdateProgressBar((int)e.Argument, worker);
    }

    private int UpdateProgressBar(int value, BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        worker.ReportProgress(value);
        return Convert.ToInt32(progressBar.Value);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

}

Thats not working (This is only some Copy/Paste arrangement, cause I have no idea on how to accomplish that, working first time with Threads in WPF). But maybe u got now a better sight, of what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to choose: use one background worker to load all the listviews or use multiple background workers, each filling a listview.

Currently you are trying to force the backgroundworker to start working on another job before the previous job has finished.

To fix this quickly: put all the code to load the listviews in the DoWork handler.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    // fill listview1
    worker.ReportProgress(percentageDone);
    // fill listview2
    worker.ReportProgress(percentageDone);
    // fill listview3
    worker.ReportProgress(percentageDone);
}
```

To use multiple Backgroundworkers create multiple Backgroundworkers:

```
var bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw1.DoWork += ...;
bw1.RunAsync(...);
var bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw2.DoWork += ...;
bw2.RunAsync(...);
var bw3 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw3.DoWork += ...;
bw3.RunAsync(...);
```

Comment: And keep in mind that you have to set the[BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx) property to `true` to enable `ReportProgress`.

Comment: the problem is, that I want to isolate the code, that means I don't want to write the "ListViewFilling" in the MainWindow Backgroundcode. I still want it in the Class StartCommand.. How one ListViewFilling looks like: `viewModel.MissingTables = schemaComparer.GetSchemaModifications<MissingTable>(viewModel.FirstSchemaToCompare, viewModel.SecondSchemaToCompare);`

Comment: Good! What you could do is put the backgroundworker in the ViewModel.

Comment: Just did so, but how can I access then my Progressbar?

Comment: Make a property Progress on the ViewModel and bind the Value property of the progress bar to it. That is MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on what "filling list view" actually means. If you're going off to a database to get data then that definitely should be on a background thread. However, if you already have the data and just need to populate the list view, then a `BackgroundWorker` won't help at all - it'll make matters worse. That's because you'll need to marshal back to the UI thread in order to access the `ListView`!

If you have a lot of data to add to a `ListView` and you want to keep the UI responsive throughout, you need to add the data in chunks in separate dispatcher messages. When a chunk has been added, queue another message to add the next chunk. This gives the dispatcher time to process other messages whilst the list is populating.

Comment: I'm getting data from database, I fill 7 Listviews at the same time, but it does not take so long.. about 3-7 seconds, so the UI does not really must be responsive..